# mapreduce, hbase and scan

Tags: java, mapreduce, hbase

I have a MapReduce job that extends the TableMapper class.  I use the TableMapperReduceUtil initTableMapperJob to setup the initial scan which works fine. Based on the rowkey retrieved from the Scan I want to run a Get (using a rowkey which is a value in the initial Scan row) on the same table within my MapReduce Map method.  How do I access the Hbase connection to the same table from within the Map method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can create a new connection in this manner:

```
Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
```

But I think in your case it will be easier to use [Spark on HBase](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-spark/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/example/hbasecontext/JavaHBaseDistributedScan.java)